# How to design a strict constraint term (never violate this constraint) for matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

It is a low-rank sparse decomposition problem: $ D= ML + S + \epsilon$, that we know the matrix D can be decompose into 2 part that one part $L$ is low rank, the other part $S$ is sparse, $\epsilon$ is noise.

I am right now solve this problem with this eqaution with Douglas-Rachford method:
$$ \min_{S,L} \quad \lambda_{1}\left\| S \right\|_{1} + \lambda_{2}\left\| L \right\|_{*} + \left\| D-MS-L \right\|_{2}$$

Where $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $S \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times z}$, $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times z}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times z}$

let $$ f(S,L) =  \lambda_{1}\left\| S \right\|_{1} + \lambda_{2}\left\| L \right\|_{*} $$

$$g(S,L) =  \left\| D-MS-L \right\|_{2}$$

Evaluating the prox-operator of $f$ reduces to separately evaluating the prox-operators of the $L_{1}$ norm and the nuclear norm. for $g(S,L)$:

$$ \text{prox}_{g}(S) =  \min _{ x } { \left\| D-MS-L \right\|  }_{ 2 }^{ 2 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2\lambda  } \left\| S-x \right\| _{ 2 }^{ 2 }$$

$$ \text{prox}_{g}(L) =  \min _{ x } { \left\| D-MS-L \right\|  }_{ 2 }^{ 2 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2\lambda  } \left\| L-x \right\| _{ 2 }^{ 2 }$$

---

I want to add another constraint that is for every element in $L$ satisfy the constraint $D-L>0$.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely? It's just a convex constraint. Just add it to the model.

Comment: @MichaelGrant , what I know about dealing with inequality constraint is using log barrier method to rewrite equation as $ \min_{S,L} \quad \left\| S \right\|_{1} + \left\| L \right\|_{*} + \left\| D-S-L \right\|_{2} -\log { \left( L-D \right)  } $,  but the result of $L-D$ is a matrix, it not works.

Comment: OK, so you're asking how to *solve* such a problem. That may sound dense but really, you haven't given us any information about *how you're solving it now*, without the constraint.

Comment: @MichaelGrant , I have edited my post.

Comment: Use a product space reformulation, and just add the indicator set of your constraint set as another term in your problem. This does, however, require you to be able to project onto the constraint set and also that the set is closed.